# Software design pattern MVC window creation strategies

Tags: java, model-view-controller, sdp

I would like to hear some opinions on window strategy creation with MVC. I'm writing a game and I want to integrate MVC into it.. And one of the questions I have is should I create all the windows and register them within controller on the start of the application and fill them when appropriate event is fired or should I create them along only when they needed? If I should create the windows only when it needed, who should be in charge of creation?

Thanks in advance,
Serhiy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create them as they are needed and let the Controller be in control of creating the window.

Comment: Ok that was what I was thing to do. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

you can consider the Swing's architecture, a modified MVC.

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/

Comment: I will need to take a closer look to the article. I was aware that Swing is using MVC. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the model
2. Create the controller
3. Link controller to model.
4. Create view
5. Link view to model.
6. Link view to controller.